# Parent Child Hierarchy Count

Tags: sql-server

[Need to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvOFv.png)

MSSQL:

I want to know the total count of each parent

Comment: INPUT 
ID Comment ParentId
1 A  0
2 B  0
3 c  1
4 d  2
5 e  3
6 f  5
7 j  4

OUTPUT

ID COUNT
1 3
2 2

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time making sense of your sample data. However, just looking at your question this will give you the total number of rows for each ParentId.

```
select ParentId, count(*)
from YourTable
group by ParentId
```